# PortAudioError: Error querying device -1 in google colab when using the sounddevice library

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-sounddevice

I've installed and imported all the required libraries (at least I think so):

```
!sudo apt-get install libportaudio2
!pip install sounddevice
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sounddevice as sd
```

And I am getting the following error when running this code:

```
wav_wave = np.array(tone, dtype=np.int16)
sd.play(wav_wave, blocking=True)
sd.stop()
```

The error below is caused by the `sd.play` function.

```
PortAudioError: Error querying device -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a virtual machine from Google collab, you can´t play an audio there. Instead, you can always display an audio object in the front-end and play it from there. Like this:

```
from IPython.display import Audio
from IPython.display import display

wn = Audio("saxriff.wav", autoplay=True)
display(wn)
```

Please note that this solution only works for notebooks, like colab. It will display something like this:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXjIX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud servers might not have microphone. That is the reason why you are getting this error.